# DB information is not renderd out to Calendar

Tags: json, fullcalendar

I've downloaded the last fullCalendar but the information in db is not renderd out, I can see the information when I use firebug(Response and in tab JSON) , but nothing is visible in Calendar.

Can someone guide me, what have I missed?

Comment: Can you show some code, please?

Answer (score 0):

This is what the code from your server should look like.  FC is very particular on how deep each event is.

```
[{"id":"1311098584475","title":"Cut the lawn","start":"2011-08-28T16:00:00-05:00","allDay":0,"fix":0,"lkd":0,"rlf":0,"end":"2011-08-28T04:30:00-05:00","nid":"2091","vcc":"Vol_Activities|8","mName":"Eric","vdesc":"Lawn Care"}]
```